# Пределы видимости переменной в js

Tags: javascript, global-variables

Здравствуйте, пишу REST API на express.js вкупе с базой данных NeDB.js. В одной из при реализации функции получения данных из базы данных я столкнулся с проблемой. Это файл Router.js

```
const express = require('express');
const Database = require('./Database')

module.exports = class Router   {

    static initialize () {
        this.api = express();

        this.api.get('/classes/:class/:number/:dayOfWeek', (req, res) => {
          console.log('new request ' + req.params.class, req.params.number, req.params.dayOfWeek)
          var lessons = Database.getScheduler(req.params.class, req.params.number, req.params.dayOfWeek);
          res.send(lessons);
      });

        this.api.listen(80);
    }

}
```

Это файл Database.js

```
const nedb = require('nedb');

module.exports = class Database {

  static initialize () {
    this.db = new nedb({filename: "scheduler"});
    this.db.loadDatabase();
  }

  static getScheduler (findingClass, findingNumber, dayOfWeek) {
    var data;
    this.db.find({class: findingClass.toString(), number: findingNumber.toString()}, (err, docs) => {

      data = {'lessons' :docs[0].lessons[Number.parseInt(dayOfWeek)]};
      //console.log(data) => "нужные данные"
    });
    //console.log(data) => undefined
    return data;
  }

}
```

Это файл Main.js

```
const Router = require('./Router');
const Database = require('./Database');

Database.initialize();
Router.initialize();
```

Проблема такая, почему в пределах анонимной функции переменная `data` хранит значение, полученное с базы данных, а за пределами анонимной функции `data` имеет значение `undefined`? И как это исправить? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо почитать про асинхронные функции. Проблема заключается в том, что анонимная функция выполняется после того, как выполняется строка:

`console.log(data) // undefined`

Потому что функция `find` ожидает ответа от базы, и чтобы не было пустого простоя, код выполняется дальше, а анонимная функция выполнится только тогда, когда данные придут.

Cделайте простой тест:

```
this.db.find({class: findingClass.toString(), number: findingNumber.toString()}, (err, docs) => {
  console.log('1');
});
console.log('2');
```

Вы заметите, что скорее всего сначала будет выведено число `2`, а только затем `1`

Comment: Да, я заметил, порядок лога, однако не додумался, что это следствие асинхронной природы данного вызова. А как мне реализовать ожидание завершения поиска? `await` ?

Comment: `async`, `await`, если не ошибаюсь (а я могу), работает только с возвращаемыми Promise, а в этой библиотеке такого насколько я понимаю нет. Я вижу 3 решения: 1. Вы передаёте функцию в свою функцию, которая будет работать с data, и её уже подсовываете, как анонимную функцию. 2. Вы создаёте собственный `Event` и подписываетесь на него. 3. Вы создаёте `Observable` и подписываетесь уже на него.

Comment: если я объявляю функцю `getScheduler` как `await`, а к вызову `this.db.find` добавлю await, разве я не добьюсь желаемого ожидания завершения работы `find`?

Comment: @nerlihmax, нет, find не возвращает промис, JS не поймёт что нужно ожидать.